# Match doesn't work on Specific String name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have a spreadsheet like this:
[image]

I'm trying to run this formula to get the value from "Total Income" under the -Call Centre header

These are the values from the NAME_INPUT sheet:

```
B71 = A1:AJ39       D71 = E1:E39
```

This is the formula which is finding result 0:

```
=ROUND(INDEX(INDIRECT("'QB IS by class'!" & NAME_INPUT!B71),MATCH("Total Income",INDIRECT("'QB IS by class'!" & NAME_INPUT!D71)),MATCH("-Call Centre",'QB IS by class'!1:1,0))/1000,0)
```

I know the formula is written correctly, because if I change "Total Income" to "PIEFACE", it'll match and give me the correct value.

Why does the string, "Total Income" cause it to have zero results. I don't see any other fields under E column with the name, "Total Income".
Even if I use, "Total Expense" that will get the correct value under -Call Centre for that row... So why does "Total Income" fail to give me a result?

The field types are all the same.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your data isn't clear, but I think you are doing an `Exact Match` so you forgot the third parameter `0` for the first `MATCH` in the formula:

> ```
> MATCH("Total Income",INDIRECT("'QB IS by class'!" & NAME_INPUT!D71))
> ```

The above term should be

```
MATCH("Total Income",INDIRECT("'QB IS by class'!" & NAME_INPUT!D71), 0)
                                                                   ^^^^
```

and the whole formula:

```
=ROUND(INDEX(INDIRECT("'QB IS by class'!" & NAME_INPUT!B71),MATCH("Total Income",INDIRECT("'QB IS by class'!" & NAME_INPUT!D71), 0),MATCH("-Call Centre",'QB IS by class'!1:1,0))/1000,0)

                                                                                                                                ^^^
```

Comment: UGGGGH! Wasted so much time trying to figure out something so simple. Omfg, I even added -1, and 1 to try and figure it out. Completely overlooking trying the 0. How.... I feel so dumb... Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `MATCH(CONCATENATE("*"&"Total Income"&"*"))` in for `MATCH("Total Income"`